# simplenews. confirmation of subscription for registered user

Tags: emails

purpose: confirmation of subscription for registered user

installed on the website simplenews module (https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews).
now on the main page there is a form to subscribe to the newsletter.

if the user is not authorized, he introduces email and sends a subscription request,
he comes to notice by email that he signed up for the newsletter and confirm the proposal (!) the desire to receive the newsletter.

if the user is authorized, he sees only the button (email enter) and if you send a subscription request, it immediately becomes signed.

can to make it so that an authorized user before activating the subscription, as well as anonymous, received a notice to activate your subscription?

Answer (score -1):

well, since no one here, I will use:

```
simplenews_subscribe_user($email, $tid, TRUE, 'website');
```